# the readonly value depends on a variable symfony4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, readonly

well I want the readonly proprety to have a value depending on a variable.

My idea is like this :

sending the variable(which is a boolean) as a parameter when rendering.

```
return $this->render('responsable/uneInscription.html.twig', [
  'form'     => $form->createView(),
  'readonly' => $readonly,
]);
```

and use the variable like this :

```
{{ form_row(form.id_diplome.niveau, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control' ,'readonly': {{readonly}} } }) }}
```

but it just doesn't work, I always get a readonly field

I am new to symfony so I don't even know if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `readonly` variable wrong. You're printing its value out with `{{  readonly }}`, rather than using it directly.

The following should work:

```
{{ form_row(form.id_diplome.niveau, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': readonly }}) }}
```

Comment: Saw that too, figured it was just a typo since that should throw a `Twig\Error\SyntaxError`

Comment: Yep, frankly I was surprised it didn't cause a syntax error (or OP at least didn't mention it).